# Retrieving one record from the database

Tags: php, arrays, error-handling, record, fetch

Just trying to display one record from the database... But receiving an error (when fetching the array)

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("school");
$iid=$_REQUEST['id2'];   //mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid

$d=mysql_query("select * from notification where noticeid=$iid");
$data=mysql_fetch_array( $d );
```

Here is my displaying criteria...

```
<tr> 
<td class=""><?php echo $data['noticeid'] ?></td>  
<td class=""><?php echo $data['notificationtitle'] ?></td>  
<td class=""><?php echo $data['notificationbody'] ?></td>  
</tr>
```

Comment: It has been resolved... There was no problem in the code above...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:  noticeid=' ".$iid." '

```
$d=mysql_query("select * from notification where noticeid='".$iid."' ");
$data=mysql_fetch_array( $d );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to quote the variable:

1. If noticeid is a string:
   `$d=mysql_query("select * from notification where noticeid='".$iid."'");`
2. If noticeid is a number:
   `$d=mysql_query("select * from notification where noticeid=".$iid);`